# How to do large-scale, batch reverse geo-coding?

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have a very large list of lat/lon coordinate pairs (>50 million). I want to attach address information to each one. Most geo/revgeo services have strict call limits. Assuming computing power isn't the issue, how can I accomplish this? Also note that time/speed are not the primary concern.

One place to start might be the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get one of the dedicated AWS geocoders for unlimited volumme processing: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results?x=0&y=0&searchTerms=geocoder

Answer (score 1):

### Intro

I have experience working with [SmartyStreets's](https://smartystreets.com) batch processing tool. They don't have call limits (paid version). But, they also don't have a Reverse Geocode API (yet!). Their batch processing is strictly for flexibility and ease-of-use in addition to normal calls. But, I am aware of a couple services that do Reverse Geocoding, and they mention batch processing on their website.

### How they work

Batch processing services generally allow you to upload your data, even arbitrarily large files. You probably want to put your data in a CSV file (type of spreadsheet) as latitude and longitude pairs. Then, their servers will process the data and alert you when you can download. It's common practice to charge money for this download, but maybe TAMU's is free?

### Suggestions on who to use

1. [Texas A&M Geoservices](https://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/ReverseGeocoding/)
2. [MapLarge](http://maplarge.com/reversegeocoding)

Both of these services have demos and developer portals to guide you along if there is something you want to research before using them.

(Full disclosure: I have worked for SmartyStreets.)

Comment: Any idea how those services operate? What base data do they use as a reference?

Comment: @Tim_K I'm pretty sure TAMU exclusively uses [US Census TIGER data](https://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/CensusIntersection/About/ReferenceSets.aspx). I don't know about MapLarge.